# Convert int (number) to string with leading zeros? (4 digits)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number formatting: how to convert 1 to "01", 2 to "02", etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972949)

How can I convert `int` to `string` using the following scheme?

- `1` converts to `0001`
- `123` converts to `0123`

Of course, the length of the string is dynamic. For this sample, it is:

```
int length = 4;
```

How can I convert like it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432734/c-sharp-pad-left-to-string , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972949/number-formatting , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325267/c-sharp-convert-int-to-string-with-padding-zeros

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Use [String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830.aspx) like this:

```
var result = input.ToString().PadLeft(length, '0');
```

Comment: c=1 a="%03d"%(c) this works perfectly

Comment: This not a good solution. Using this, you have to figure out the current length of the numbers and add the right amount of zeroes. E.g. 2 zeroes for 12 and 1 zero for 123. Using .ToString("Dx") is much better.

Comment: That is not true. PadLeft takes the total number of letters as an argument, not the one to add. So "1".PadLeft(4, '0') is "0001".

Comment: Not a good pattern, you allocate and copy the string twice and just using the most naive solution you know. `ToString` has an argument just for this purpose, use that.

Comment: Jeffs solution below would be better

Answer (score 116):

Use the formatting options available to you, use the [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString) format string.  It is far more flexible and requires little to no maintenance compared to direct string manipulation.

To get the string representation using at least 4 digits:

```
int length = 4;
int number = 50;
string asString = number.ToString("D" + length); //"0050"
```

Answer (score 100):

Use the ToString() method - [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) numeric format strings. Have a look at the MSDN article *[How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)*.

```
string text = no.ToString("0000");
```

Comment: string text = no:0000; // is the same but shorter

Answer (score 4):

`val.ToString("".PadLeft(length, '0'))`

Comment: With the new C# String interpolations , in this example length of 4

var paddedValue = $"{intValue:D4}"