# 0 Character Problem in the beggining DateTime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

I got every part of date in the code that you can see below. But the problem is if we consider today's date I need day and month as 02 not as 2.

I need that 0 char in the beggining. How can I manage it?

```
DateTime dategift = DateTime.Now;

var year = dategift.Year.ToString();
var month = dategift.Month.ToString();
var day = dategift.Day.ToString();
var hour = dategift.Hour.ToString();
var min = dategift.Minute.ToString();
var sec = dategift.Second.ToString();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# pad left to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432734/c-sharp-pad-left-to-string)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-padleft-method/

Comment: `dategift.Day.ToString("00")`

Comment: You are aware there is relatively good support for formatting datetime values directly rather than deconstructing/composing the individual elements, right?

Comment: Use  **"MM"** for double digits month and  **"dd"** for double digits days.

`string month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leading Zero Date Format C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461098/leading-zero-date-format-c-sharp)

Comment: @D.Kastier If it's a `DateTime`, why not just use the built-in way of date formatting instead?

Comment: It is mainly a matter of concept. It is possible to use 0 guide or date format. `DateTime.Now.ToStrin("dd")` and `var day = dategift.Day.ToString("00");`

Answer (score 2):

use the [Zero placeholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

```
string day = dategift.Day.ToString("00");
```

or [the "dd" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#ddSpecifier)

```
string day = dategift.ToString("dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to format the date, you can do so without pulling out all the various values as strings.

Something like:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```